# Changed "name" attribute to "id" but images don't show

Tags: html, w3c, w3c-validation

Error: The name attribute on the img element is obsolete. Use the id attribute instead.

`<img src name="slide" width="1714" height="500" alt="slideshow" />`

Above you can see I have this error that's asking me to change the 'name' to 'id', however when I try this it end's up making my images not appear. So essentially the 'id' doesn't work but the 'name' does. Any ideas?

https://gyazo.com/ff5c6b39d5a1b649027d2fca57a1ffa1

As you can see in the first image the code is working when it is 
`<img src name=""/>`

```
    <script>
    var i = 0; // Start Point
    var images = []; // Images Array
    var time = 3000; // Time Between Switch`

    // Image List
    // This holds an array of all my images
    images[0] = "images/img_house.png";
    images[1] = "images/img_staff.jpg";
    images[2] = "images/img_desk.jpg";
    images[3] = "images/img_coinstack.jpg";

    // Change Image
    function changeImg() {
      document.slide.src = images[i];

      // Check If Index Is Under Max
      if (i < images.length - 1) {
        // Add 1 to Index
        i++;
      } else {
        // Reset Back To O
        i = 0;
      }

      // Run function every x seconds
      setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
    }

    // Run function when page loads
    window.onload = changeImg;

  </script>
  <section>
    <img src name="slide" width="1714" height="500" alt="slideshow" />
  </section>`
```

Below I have changed the code to `<img src id=""/>` and it no longer works, it shows the alt text.

https://gyazo.com/634a5fa6db7e1acf22a55815f19d6da2

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question so we can see what you're attempting to do

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Did you change your javascript to reflect the change from name to an id?

Comment: There's nothing in my javascript that mentions it being either id or name as far as I can see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your function you insert it using the `name` attribute "slide". But an `id` is not a `name` and must be fetched from the document. So

`document.getElementById("slide").src = images[i];`

Also, the `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.